# Get image Asynchronously and setting setNeedsDisplay

Tags: objective-c, setneedsdisplay, dispatch-async

This code is in in a cell initialization routine that sets up the elements of a custom cell.  It gets the image from the web asynchronously.  But I need it to redraw once it's done.

This is my snippet of code:

```
dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^{

    //Look for the image in a repository, if it's not there
    //load the image from the web (a slow process) and return it
    mCover.image = [helperMethods imageManagerRequest:URL];

    //Set the image to be redrawn in the next draw cycle
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [mCover setNeedsDisplay];
    });

});
```

But it doesn't redraw the UIImageView.  I've tried to also redraw the entire cell, and that doesn't work either.  Your help is much appreciated.  I've been trying to fix this for some time!

Comment: Are you returning a UIImage or UIImageView?  Perhaps you're inadvertently assigning an image to an image view?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `setNeedsDisplay`, you should set the image on main thread as Apple have mentioned in [their documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html).

> Note: For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an
>   application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes
>   derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your
>   application’s user interface in any way.

This should fix your problem:

```
dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^{

    //Look for the image in a repository, if it's not there
    //load the image from the web (a slow process) and return it
    UIImage *image = [helperMethods imageManagerRequest:URL];

    //Set the image to be redrawn in the next draw cycle
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        mCover.image = image;
    });

});
```